# What does function "mapped" do? And why there is something wrong with matrix dimensions?

Tags: function, matlab, matrix

Here is doing the simulation that the all data carriers in one OFDM frame are modulated using QPSK, and the codes were from others, so I don't understand it well. I think there is something wrong with the following codes, where I set Y = Yint', and Yint is a 4x1512 double matrix, and Nmax is equal to 1512, when I run it, which turned out to be

```
??? Error using ==> eq
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> mapping at 5
if Y(k,:)== [0 0];
```

I hope it's clear. And I have no idea about the function "mapped", can anybody tell me what does it do? Thanks!

```
for k = 1:Nmax;
if Y(k,:)== [0 0];
mapped(k)= +1+1j;
elseif Y(k,:)== [0 1];
mapped(k)= +1-1j;
elseif Y(k,:)== [1 0];
mapped(k)= -1+1j;
elseif Y(k,:)== [1 1];
mapped(k)= -1-1j;
end
end
end
```

Comment: `mapped` looks like an array, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

mapped() is not a standard function in MATLAB. Use "edit mapped" to display the code of mapped().

Comment: Oh yes!Thank you very much, I forgot to create "mapped", I thought it was a standard function before.

Comment: Your welcome, but as Oli said, in your code mapped looks like an array, not a function :)

Comment: An array? If I get mapped array, what will it serve for the QPSK modulation? Can I show it as a figure?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Y(k,:)` is not the same size as `[0 0]`.  Or in other words, `Y` doesn't have two columns.

Comment: Oh right, I click twice on the element presented in Yint, which only has one dimension. Thank you very much!